# How to tell Vim: Open current document in Browser and Refresh?

Tags: vim, browser

Right now I open archives in my browser (localhost) with the follow line: `:! start "http://localhost" file:///"%:p""<CR>`.

It is possible to tell Vim: Open Firefox and hit refresh? (I don't want to refresh the current document I'm editing in Vim because if I open, for instance, the current CSS, the results won't show up in the browser.

PS: I'm using Windows XP (Unfortunately)

Comment: Umm, is it really that tedious to hit `<F5>` in the browser?

Comment: It's not just F5. It's Alt + Tab (until I find Firefox) and them F5.

Comment: If you can deal with closing firefox everytime, firefox has a switch to force it to open in a new window.  I believe that would probably get you the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115 extension for automatic page reloads?